# Using the force-layout physics for seperated elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

I use the force layout in D3.js v4. Now I want to click on a node and use the force physics like `collide` for that one node only.

The simulation for every node on the entire SVG is this:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.index
    }))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 8
    }).iterations(16))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(chartWidth / 2, chartWidth / 2))
```

Now I want to change the `collide` behavior for the one node I clicked on to push other nodes away or attract them.

Is there someone who knows a solution? I tried a bit with a filter function and stop/restart the layout, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said: *"I want to change the collide behavior for the one node i clicked on to push other nodes away or attract them"*.

If you want to *attract* the other nodes using `d3.forceCollide`, you're using the wrong tool for the task.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceCollide):

> The collision force treats nodes as circles with a given radius, rather than points, and prevents nodes from overlapping.

Thus, `collide` basically pushes the other nodes away, to avoid overlapping.

That being said, this solution deals only with the first part of your problem: *"I want to change the collide behavior for the one node i clicked on to **push** other nodes away"*.

There are different ways for doing this. In my solution, when you click a node, it changes the `r` property in the bound data:

```
d3.select(this).datum().r = 20;
```

Without redrawing the actual SVG circle. That pushes the other nodes away, maintaining the clicked node at the same size.

Here is the demo (click on the nodes):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => colour(i));

node.on("click", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll("circle").data().forEach(d => d.r = 6);
    d3.select(this).datum().r = 20;
    simulation.nodes(data);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, can i ask a question? I did not understand very well your code. This line `var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6...` confuses me a little bit, because i thought that `map()` is used to use a function on an existing array and gets a new array with that used function? In this case i do not see, what the old array is?

Comment: I did that just to create 20 objects in an array in a faster way. The old array is `[0, 1, 2, 3... ,20]`, made by `d3.range(20)`.

Comment: @Derick I have to be honest with you: when we spend some time writing code for an answer and OP simply says "thanks" it's a bit annoying. I normally mentally blacklist these people and ignore their future questions. Don't be like this... You don't have to accept an answer, but upvoting it is an easy and cheap token of appreciation.

Comment: @Gerado: My bad, i spend a lot of time trying to understand every line of the code (still got a lot of questions) and then i just forgot to upvote. Also, sometimes i post something and leave the computer for some days, so i am not always updated about the answers. To be fair: If you look at my previous posts, when possible, i always upvoted and accepted peoples help.

Comment: But in the future  will upvote asap without delay. Sorry for this.

Comment: can you maybe help me with this line? `d3.selectAll("circle").data().forEach(d => d.r = 6)`  I have never used `data()`with empty brackets before, so i don't know what data you are using the `forEach` function?

Comment: No worries, Derick. I know you from previous questions and I know you normally don't do that, that's why I was comfortable to write what I wrote in the above comment. Regarding that line: It's selecting all the circle elements and getting the data bound to them (when you write `data()` without any argument it's a getter, not a setter). Then, it overwrites the `r` property of all the data to 6, which makes all the circle elements having an `r` attribute of 6 in their data (but this doesn't change the actual DOM element).

Comment: Yeah, i try my best in the next postings to give upvotes. I got one more question: Your answer was regarding to that line i asked you about. But what is about the next line? `d3.selectAll(".circles").data().r = 6;`? Isn`t it the same?

Comment: Ops, my bad, this last one shouldn't be there. I just edited the snippet.

Comment: But why it was still working fine? Is it the same line, just rewritten?

Comment: No, that line was not working. It's not the same of the `forEach`. I accidentally left it there when I was writing the snippet.

Comment: The radius size of the circles (which you can see with your eyes) won`t change when click on, because you use the getter?

Comment: No, that's not the reason. It won't change because nowhere in the code I tell the circle to change the radius! I'm changing only the data (and for getting the data I'm ussing the getter).

Comment: Thank you. When i got circles with a constant radius   `var node = ....attr("r", 7)`               then how can i use correctly the collide force line `var simulation = .....force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;` ?

Comment: In the colide, set the radius that is the *minimal* radius between two adjacent circles.

Comment: When use .map(), you want to perform a single operation on all elements in an array and make a new array out of it. So with the line `var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6
}));` you create an array of 30 elements and then you do what exactly with the help of .map()? Btw: i just found out, that it is possible to upvote every comment. I thought that only the "big" answers are possible to upvote.

Comment: That's just for creating 30 objects wrapped in an array.

Comment: Hey, i would like to ask one more thing when using datum().                               In the documentation it says about # selection.datum([value]) : If a value is not specified, returns the bound datum for the first (non-null) element in the selection. This is generally useful only if you know the selection contains exactly one element. Is this also possible when use data()? In your code it would be `d3.select(this).data().r = 20;`

Comment: If you use `data()`, it will return an array. Test it.

Comment: I thought about that, because i am trying to filter some nodes by color in an extra array and increase the

Comment: This time i created a seperate button and  i want  to use `data()` to increase the collide radius of many nodes when click on the button. When a filtered number of nodes is stored in an array called `abc`, i tried to keep the whole code of the `.on` fuction for the button and only changed your line into this line:  `d3.select(abc).data().r = 100;`. But this idea does not work. Can you tell me, what i make wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Please, post **another** question. If you ask it here in the comments, I'm the only one reading it.