# Change the collision behavior of many nodes stored in an array

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

when using the force layout in d3.js it is possible to push nodes away with the help of the collision force by increasing an imaginary radius that surrounds the nodes.

I created a seperate button named `button` and i want to use `.data()` (to select a whole array) to increase the collide radius into 40 of many nodes when click on that button. For example when a filtered number of nodes is stored in an array called `abc`, i tried this code:

```js
var node =......
    .on("click", function(d, i) {

        abc = start && start.path(d) || [];

        node.style("fill", function(n) {
            if (n == start ) {             
               return "yellow";
            } else if ( n == d) {
               return "green"
            } else if (abc.includes(n)) {
               return "red"
            } else {
               return "lightgrey"
            }
         .....
      }});

button.on("click", function(d) {
   d3.selectAll("circle").data().forEach(d => d.r = 6);
   d3.select(abc).data().r = 40;
   simulation.nodes(data);
   simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})
```

I am able to click on 2 nodes and store these 2 nodes and all the nodes between them in the array`abc`. This is possible with the help of the d3.js function `path()`which returns the shortest way between 2 nodes.
But unfortunally it does not work. Maybe there is someone who can help me with the problem. The basic idea of pushing nodes away is already discussed in here: [Using the force-layout physics for seperated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915510/using-the-force-layout-physics-for-seperated-elements)
Thanks so much!

Comment: You mean quotes in this line? `d3.select("abc").data().r = 40;`?

Comment: Yes. Are you selecting a tag? I don't believe so. Also, please specify how abc is created.

Comment: I just edited the code.

Comment: Still difficult to help you. Just answer this: is abc a d3 selection?

Comment: I think there is the mistake i made. Basically i just tried a bit around. The previous line was `abc.data().r = 40;`. I just tried to get access to the radius in an array of nodes in general with that line.

Comment: That's not how you change the data. Is abc a d3 selection?

Comment: No, just a normal array.

Comment: That being the case, how do you associate the nodes with that array? What nodes should have their radiuses increased? You see, it's very hard to help you without that information.

Comment: I just edited the code again. The result of the code: When click on 2 nodes, it highlights these 2 nodes and the nodes between them with colors or different sizes. These highlighted nodes are now stored in `abc` and i want these highlighted nodes to increase their collide radius. Maybe it would be also a better option to use `.filter()` ? For example to filter the new highlighted attribute of these nodes and use the attributes to increase the collide radius?

Comment: The question is: **how** are the nodes stored in `abc`? You said that `abc` is not a d3 selection, but a simple array instead. So, how can I select the node given that `abc` array? That's all I need to know.

Comment: I just edited the code one more time. I hope i can understand your question right. I think you cannot select the nodes from that `abc` array directly. The only way to get access for example to red nodes is to filter them by the new given red attribute.

Comment: I will read your answer tomorrow, the timeshift makes it hard for me to stay awake. Thanks so much for the help, Gerardo.

Comment: Well, I can't help you. This is frustrating because the task here is very, very simple, but I can't write any code (and I won't write pseudocode) without knowing the content of that array and the nodes selection. I hope someone else can help you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the honesty. Let me try to ask you this way: I am able to filter out nodes by color and change the styling with this code: `node.filter(function(d){
        return this.style.fill === 'pink';
      })
   .style(......); ` This works very good. Now i want to use this trick to change the collide radius in the same way. I tried some codes, but nothing worked. My last try was `node.filter(function(d){
        return this.style.fill === 'pink';
      })
   .this.data().r = 200;` You got a idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several comments I finally have an idea of how you are filtering the node selection.

In the following demo, the circles have 4 different colours:

```
var colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

node.attr("fill", (d, i) => colours[i%4]);
```

So, when you click the button, we simply filter the nodes with "red" colour and increase their `r` property, making the collide radius increase, using `each`:

```
node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
}).each(d => d.r = 40);
```

If you want use `data` as a getter, you can do it with a `forEach`:

```
node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
}).data().forEach(d => d.r = 40);
```

Which has the same result.

Here is a demo, all red nodes will push away the other nodes after the click, with a collide radius of 40:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => colours[i%4]);

d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
  node.filter(function(){
   return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
  }).each(d=>d.r = 40);
    simulation.nodes(data);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<br>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks again. In my case (i am using the force layout in combination with `hierarchy` ) i had to replace the line `return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"` into `return this.style.fill === 'red'` to make it work. Not sure, why is that. Before i made this replacement, i tried to change `attr` into `style` to make it looks like this: ``return d3.select(this).style("fill") === "red"`` But this also did not worked out for me. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: If you set the fill using `style`, you have to change using `style`.

Comment: Do you know, if it is possible to change the distance (length) of the links in the same way? I tried just to use this`d3.forceSimulation().force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(function(d) {
        return d.r + 10;
    })`, but this did not worked out.

Comment: @Derick please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and, as I always say, as a new question.