# Filter out nodes and turn them inactive

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

I am using d3.js with the force-layout. Now, based on the answer of this question:
[Change the collision behavior of many nodes stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404896/change-the-collision-behavior-of-many-nodes-stored-in-an-array)

it is possible to filter out red nodes and push other nodes away (increase the collide attribute) by clicking the "click me" button. It works very good, but now I wish that the blue nodes are not affected by the push away action of the red nodes. That means, the green and yellow nodes are get pushed away, but the blue nodes stay on the original position. So I am looking for a way to turn these blue nodes inactive in the force layout. Maybe some of you can help. Thanks guys!

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => colours[i%4]);

d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
  node.filter(function(){
   return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
  }).each(d=>d.r = 40);
    simulation.nodes(data);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<br>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for doing this is checking if it is the first time the simulation runs and, if it's not, filtering out the blue circles:

```
simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        if (firstTime) {
            node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
        } else {
            node.filter(function(e) {
                return d3.select(this).attr("fill") != "blue"
            }).attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
        }
    });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var firstTime = true;

var colours = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
  r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r + 1;
  }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", d => d.r)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => colours[i % 4]);

d3.select("button").on("click", function(d) {
  firstTime = false;
  node.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).attr("fill") === "red"
  }).each(d => d.r = 40);
  simulation.nodes(data);
  simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
})

simulation.nodes(data)
  .on("tick", d => {
    if (firstTime) {
      node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    } else {
      node.filter(function(e) {
        return d3.select(this).attr("fill") != "blue"
      }).attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<br>
<svg></svg>
```

By the way, the result you want (*"the green and yellow nodes are get pushed away, but the blue nodes stay on the original position"*) is visually unpleasant.

Comment: Can you explain, for what we need to check if the simulation runs for the first time or not?

Comment: Because you don't want the blue circles pilling up at the top left corner.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. Great help as always. I just opened a new question about a similiar problem. Maybe you can take a look if you got time.